# How to remove a list and make it just comma separated in Snowflake column?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a list in a column in Snowflake table as shown below. All I want to do is to remove the brackets and double quotes and just keep it as comma separated. Please help me achieve this.

```
[
  "Availability",
  "Category Level 1",
  "Crawl Date",
  "Price",
  "Retailer"
]
```

Expcted:

```
  Availability,
  Category Level 1,
  Crawl Date,
  Price,
  Retailer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_to_string) converts an array to text:

```
SELECT ['Availability',
        'Category Level 1',
        'Crawl Date',
        'Price',
        'Retailer' 
       ] AS arr
  ,ARRAY_TO_STRING(arr, ',');
```

Output:

[image]